# In wordpress, how to redirect after a comment back to the referring page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have comments enabled on different types of pages in Wordpress (archive, tag, search, main page), and after a user posts a comment I would like them to be redirected back to their referring page, not to the single post page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put this in your **functions.php**:

```
add_filter('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment');
function redirect_after_comment($location)
{
return $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the WordPress [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). It's the proper way to extend or customize functionality in WordPress. Once you've read a little about the API, check out the Action Reference (*I would post the link but StackOverflow wont let me*).

You will need at least two action hooks to complete your task:

1. **comment_post** - run directly after a comment is added to your database
2. **comment_form** - run whenever the comment form is printed from a theme template

Basically, we want to capture the HTTP_REFERER variable in the persistent $_SESSION whenever the user first sees the comment form. Then we redirect them once they post the comment.

Create `comment-redirect.php` in the WordPress `wp-content/plugins` folder.
Here's a rough idea of what you would put in this file (I leave it up to you to refine/test it):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Post Comment Redirect
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: Redirects you to the previous page after posing a comment
Version: 0.1a
Author: Anonymous
Author URI: http://example.com
License: GPL2
*/

// Run whenever a comment is posted to the database.
// If a previous page url is set, then it is unset and
// the user is redirected.
function post_comment_redirect_action_comment_post() {
  if (isset($_SESSION['PCR_PREVIOUS_PAGE_URL'])) {
    $ref = $_SESSION['PCR_PREVIOUS_PAGE_URL'];
    unset($_SESSION['PCR_PREVIOUS_PAGE_URL']);
    header('Location: '.$ref);
  }
}

// Run whenever comment form is shown.
// If a previous page url is not set, then it is set.
function post_comment_redirect_action_comment_form() {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['PCR_PREVIOUS_PAGE_URL'])) {
    if ($ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
      $_SESSION['PCR_PREVIOUS_PAGE_URL'] = $ref;
    }
  }
}

add_action('comment_post', 'post_comment_redirect_action_comment_post');
add_action('comment_form', 'post_comment_redirect_action_comment_form');
```

Once you have your plugin saved, enable it in the wp-admin Plugins section (usually found near h**p://your-website-address.com/wp-admin).

Comment: Wow, thanks! Though I have almost no clue what to do with this. I saved the file and activated the plugin and it doesn't seem to work as is, but I guess I will have to play with it.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against returning `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` as it's not reliable.

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Source https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Here's an alternative

```
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', function ( $location ) {
    return get_permalink($_POST['comment_post_ID']);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, wordpress has a custom built in function [`wp_get_referer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_referer/) to handle the referer url for a better consistency (as per @Timofey's comment).

```
<?php

add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'wpso_4534713' );

function wpso_4534713( $location ) {

    $location = wp_get_referer();
        
    return $location;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
header("Location: $ref");
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do I put this? Sorry, I'm new to php and Wordpress in general. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Never used WP, sorry. Look for function or file where comment insertion happens, after comment is inserted in database, that's when redirection happens, usually header function is used, or maybe WP has it's internal redirect function, anyway, you can send header and exit script.