# Redirect Users to custom page after comment Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, comments

i am making custom comment box on custom file and i made new comment file in Wordpress that is copy of wp-comment-post.php and my new file is wp-comments.php now when i post comment it published successfully but redirect to this url wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.punjabidharti.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

but i want to redirect user to specific page 
this is my form:

```
<form action="https://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-comments.php" method="post" id="commentform">
    <p>
    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="textarea" value="" size="22" tabindex="1" />
    <label for="author">
    Name    </label>
    (required)  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="22" tabindex="2" class="textarea" />
    <label for="email">
    E-mail    </label>
    (required)  </p>

   <p>
    <label for="comment"><strong>Your Comment</strong></label>
    <br />
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="50" rows="10" tabindex="4" class="textarea"></textarea>
  </p>
<p>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" tabindex="5" value="submit" class="Cbutton" />

    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="128278" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/punjabi/sikhism/satnam-singh-ferozepuriya/" />
  </p>
</form>
```

this is i think redirect code in wp-comments.php

```
$location = empty( $_POST['redirect_to'] ) ? get_comment_link( $comment ) : $_POST['redirect_to'] . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;

$location = apply_filters( 'comment_post_redirect', $location, $comment );
```

please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In wordpress, how to redirect after a comment back to the referring page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534713/in-wordpress-how-to-redirect-after-a-comment-back-to-the-referring-page)

Comment: You will need to update the `return $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];` from the duplicate question to your page.

Comment: no i don't want to edit function.php , i only want to edit custom file that i have created if its possible somehow ? @disinfor

Comment: Why don't you want to edit `functions.php`? That's what it's there for.

Comment: i will show that comment box on custom posts not for all posts , that's why @disinfor

Comment: Then wrap it in a conditional `if` statement. It doesn't have to fire the action unless you're on a custom post type `if ( is_singular('post_type_here') ) : all your referrer actions; endif;`